# DNS - how to retrieve the complete zone definition in bind format?

Tags: dns, bind, zone

Since I saw the company where I registered my domain was offering an API to manage it, I am trying to set up something like a dynamic dns service.
Here you can find what the api allows me to do. https://console.online.net/en/api/#api_base_documentation
When I try to patch or post something to the active zone I am facing a permission denied.
Given :

- I found nothing to copy the active zone.
- I should be able to create a whole new zone from a "bind string".

I am looking for a way to extract the "bind string" of the active version of the zone.
I couldn't find anything relevant with dig, named, nslookup, whois options.

Any idea of how to get all dns records of a domain in bind format with a single command ?

Comment: If your current nameserver accept AXFR requests, just do one and you will get back with dig the zone in "Zonefile" format. So `dig AXFR @ns1.authoritative.example somedomain.example`, but AXFR is rarely open publicly.

Comment: `; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> AXFR @ns1.online.net francoismenetrier.eu
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
; Transfer failed.`
I will assume it means it is not open.

Comment: Indeed. So you need to ask your provider. But reading again your question, to do a "dynamic DNS service" you do not need the full access of the zone content. You need an API, or a way to use directly DNS UPDATE messages, with your provider where you can add or remove records, one by one. No need of the full zone.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help, I couldn't find any way, with this api, to update the active version of the zone (permission denied) or to copy a zone (to build a reference version and make an activable copy of it). So I am building it record by record, having to call the api for each one. As I want to minimize the interactions I am now thinking of making my own dns with bind9 (as a stealth masterif I can)

Comment: "So I am building it record by record, having to call the api for each one." I understand why you come to that, but this is the wrong way to solve your problem and will only create you more problems later. Find a provider that lets you change a record in your zone the way you need it instead. As for doing DNS yourself, this is obviously an option and solution, but make sure to fully understand how the DNS works as otherwise you can shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Well, I just had to better look at the management console, I can download the bind file. I will be able to maintain this file and use it to create new zone version with updated file and activate it...